# How to disable 'foreign key validation' while restoring PostgreSQL database process

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to restore my postgres database restore. Size of database is around 23 GB. While restoring I noticed that it creates foreign key on table after loading of data, which takes a lot of time.

So I was hoping is there some way to disable foreign keys validation while restoring database and enable it later after restoration is complete.

Regards,
Mohit Dubey

Comment: no, but can comment out the line in dump file

Comment: If you did a custom-format (`pg_dump -Fc`) dump, and were restoring using `pg_restore`, you could use the `--disable-triggers` option. This won't work if you're using `psql` to restore a SQL-format dump.